# Grails asset-pipeline custom theme support

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to implement theme from external developers in grails using asset-pipeline plugin
theme structure:

```
-css
--patterns
--plugins
--animate.css
--bootstrap.css
...
-js
--plugins
--bootstrap.js
...
-img
-font-awesome
--css
--fonts
--less
--scss
```

...

If I import all files in appropriative directories of assets (stylesheets, javascript, images) many problem arise, ex:

```
-project/img/sample.jpg not found
-assets/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found) (there is no such file)
```

and variuos js errors
when I use resource plugins and keep theme's folders structure everything works fine

So my question is how to use asset-pipeline with predefined theme?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with using `<asset:javascript src="xx.js" />` for each entry in order of source page